# How can I solve the problem of Canon PowerShot SX230 HS’s monitor?

Tags: canon, powershot

I have a Canon PowerShot SX230 HS. It works very well, but after a while, the monitor displays everything in yellow. Would you please educate me on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Your camera doesn't work very well and should be serviced (or replaced), some electronic component that handles the blue channel of your display is getting bad (heat, wear (capacitor)).